# Gaussian with prior $p(\mu, \Sigma) \propto |\Sigma|^{-(d+1)/2}$. Why is the posterior $\Sigma \mid y \sim \text{Inv-Wishart}(S^{-1})$?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, bayesian, gaussian

According to [Gelman et al book](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/%7Egelman/book/BDA3.pdf), page 73, if

$p(\mu, \Sigma) \propto |\Sigma|^{-(d+1)/2}$

then

$\Sigma \mid y \sim \text{Inv-Wishart}(S^{-1})$ with $n-1$ degrees of freedom

for

$$S = \sum_i (y_i - \bar{y})(y_i - \bar{y})^T$$

I cannot get the inverse, $S^{-1}$, am I missing something please? Here is how I do it:

By construction any matrix $\sum_i X_i X_i^T$ will have the Wishart distribution if $X$ is drawn from the multivariate normal distribution (with known covariance matrix). Hence $S$ will follow the Wishart with $n-1$ degrees of freedom (conditional on $\Sigma$):

$$S \sim W_{n-1}(\Sigma)$$

with density:

$$
\operatorname{p}(S \mid \Sigma) =  \frac{  |S|^{  \frac{1}{2}(n-d-2)  } \exp\Big[ -\frac{1}{2} \operatorname{Tr}(\Sigma^{-1} S) \Big]  }{  2^{\frac{1}{2}(n-1)d }  |\Sigma|^{(n-1)/2} \Gamma_d(\frac{n-1}{2})    }
$$

From Bayes theorem:

$p(\Sigma \mid S) \,\, p(S) = p(S \mid \Sigma) \,\, p(\Sigma)$
and since $S\sim W_{n-1}(\Sigma)$ we get:

\begin{align}
 \operatorname{p}(\Sigma \mid S, \text{data})   & \propto\operatorname{p}(S \mid \Sigma) \cdot |\Sigma|^{-(d+1)/2}  \nonumber \\
   & \propto |\Sigma|^{-(n+d)/2} \exp\big[ -\frac{1}{2} \operatorname{Tr}(\Sigma^{-1} \, S)\big] \nonumber
\end{align}

Isnt the last one the density (up to a scalar) of the Inv-Wishart($S$)? According to the book, it should have been the Inv-Wishart($S^{-1}$) instead.

What am i doing wrong please?